# MYSQL generated dropdown list

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, drop-down-menu

Im looking to create a series of drop down boxes (4 in total) which are populated from content from a MYSQL database.

Once the content from each box has been selected, the data can then be submitted and all the results will appear on the page.

Ive used the following code to create a dropdown list, but it displays all 70 entries in the database for the number of bedrooms.  Im only wanting to display numbers 1 to 10 for example, not limiting to 10 but just a list, 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 displayed, even though for example there is multiple enteries for the number 2 etc
The website link for this is http://www.holidayaviemore.com

Any help is much appreciated

```
<?php

$sql = "SELECT bedrooms FROM properties";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

echo "<select name='property'>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<option value='" . $row['bedrooms'] . "'>" . $row['bedrooms'] . "</option>";
}
echo "</select>";

?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Just add `LIMIT 10` to the end of your `$sql` query.  This will solve your problem:

`$sql = "SELECT bedrooms FROM properties LIMIT 10";`

However, is this what you want?  Which 10 would you like to display?  Before the `LIMIT 10` you may want to order the results by something.

E.g. let's say you have a record called `name` in the table `bedrooms`.  Let's also say you want to order by `name` (you probably will want to change this to a more relevant field I would have thought).  You could then say something like:

`$sql = "SELECT bedrooms FROM properties ORDER BY name LIMIT 10";`

Does this help?

**EDIT**

You want this: "instead of limiting to 10 entries i would just like the numbers 1 to 10 to appear in the dropdown list".  Here's how you do it:

```
$sql = "SELECT bedrooms FROM properties LIMIT 10";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

echo "<select name='property'>";
$count = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
   echo "<option value='" . $row['bedrooms'] . "'> " . $count . " " . $row['bedrooms'] . "</option>";
   $count++;
}
echo "</select>";
```

I think you want the limit too though?  If not, remove it

Comment: thanks for your help, instead of limiting to 10 entries i would just like the numbers 1 to 10 to appear in the dropdown list

Answer (score 2):

There are two possibilities to achieve this:

you can limit the sql query:

```
$sql = "SELECT bedrooms FROM properties LIMIT 10";
```

So are only 10 items returned.

The other option is that you can make a counter in the while-loop, and check if the value of it is greater than ten.

Comment: thanks for your help, instead of limiting to 10 entries i would just like the numbers 1 to 10 to appear in the dropdown list

Answer (score 2):

Write limit at the end of your query:

```
$sql = "SELECT bedrooms FROM properties LIMIT bedrooms 0,10";
```

Answer (score 2):

To display numbers 1 to 10 you just want to add LIMIT 0,10 to your query.

It should then look like this: `SELECT bedrooms FROM properties LIMIT 0,10`